# How can i create subfolder for fonts?

Tags: android

I have multiple font. I want to categorize fonts by subfolder.

[Fonts in XML](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml)

my_font_family.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font app:fontStyle="normal" app:fontWeight="400" app:font="@font/subfolder/myfont-Regular"/>
    <font app:fontStyle="italic" app:fontWeight="400" app:font="@font/subfolder/myfont-Italic" />
</font-family>
```

But subfolder not detect by android studio.

Comment: Obviously you cannot. Same with any resource.